# How can I fix Python's invalid addition?

Tags: python

Why does Python calculate the addition of 88.6 and 0.8 and get the result 89.39999999999999 ?
And how to fix it?

```
$ python
Python 3.8.13 (default, Jul 20 2022, 13:16:07) 
[Clang 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 88.6+0.8
89.39999999999999
```

Comment: this is valid floating point addition according to IEEE 754 Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic. this has nothing to do with Python.